# Benefit of using OldState / PrevState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I don't understand completely the benefit of using oldState / prevState.
In the tutorial the code was changed from this :

```
  const DeleteClick = (id) => {
    SetMylist(Elems.filter(Elem => id !== Elem.id))
  }
```

to this :

```
  const DeleteClick = (id) => {
    SetMylist(OldElems => {
      return OldElems.filter(Elem => id !== Elem.id)
    })
  }
```

The guy said in the tutorial that if we use oldState / prevState then we get the most recent ( updated ) version of the state variable.

Comment: react apps has a lifecycle, when executing the state update, the variable is maybe not up to date with the lifecycle. meaning it has an old state. In your Example MyList could be updated (from outside) at the same time.

Comment: @Sysix Can you tell me pls an example ?

Comment: Imagine `Elems` being a central part of your app. Different parts may access it at different times asynchronous. So while you in your example are trying to remove one element from the list, annother part of the app is trying to add one element. So when you use `Elems` you may not have the latest updates as it is the current version being rendered. So someone else is adding an element and you remove your element and replace `Elems` with your old list (with the element removed). The newly added element just disapears.

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)?

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to learn what the difference between setState and prevState is and what the benefit of prevState is from [https://www.delftstack.com/howto/react/react-setstate-prevstate/#:~:text=setState%20is%20the%20primary%20method,that%20component%2C%20we%20use%20this](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/react/react-setstate-prevstate/#:%7E:text=setState%20is%20the%20primary%20method,that%20component%2C%20we%20use%20this).